# How to guarantee a unique id without using GUID?

Tags: c#, .net, database-design

My multi-threaded program for invoice management's invoice class:

```
public class Invoice
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string BillTo { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string GeneralDescription { get; set; }
        public float Tax { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

The invoice no field should be incremented when a user creates a new invoice:

```
    {
        private static object _Synchronizer;
        public int MaxTillLoad;
        static BetterSerialGenerator()
        {
            _Synchronizer = new object();
        }
        public int Load()
        {
            lock (_Synchronizer)
            {
                GetMaxNumberClass MaxObtainer = new();
                MaxTillLoad = MaxObtainer.GetLargestInvoiceNo();
                return MaxTillLoad;
            }
        } 
        public int GenerateSerial(int MaxNoTillLoad)
        {
            lock (_Synchronizer)
            {
                return Interlocked.Increment(ref MaxNoTillLoad);
            }
        }
        public int GetSerial()
        {
            int maxtillload;
            maxtillload= this.Load();
            return this.GenerateSerial(maxtillload);
        }
    }
```

My function for inserting into MongoDB :

```
 public Task CreateInvoice(Invoice invoice)

        {
            _SerialGenerator.Load();
            invoice.InvoiceNo = _SerialGenerator.GetSerial();
            return InvoiceCollection.InsertOneAsync(invoice);  
        }
```

This generates the incremental id and inserts data into database. Now if I delete a record that has the maximum number, increment would cause duplication in invoice no. I need to guarantee that invoice no is unique even if an invoice is deleted.

I don't want to use a GUID. Should I save maximum Id and on deletion check if the Id is the maximum, if so make sure that maximum is in the file? What is the cleanest way to do so?

I decided to cache maximum like this :

```
    {
        private const string CacheKey = "maximuminvoiceno";
        private static object _Synchronizer;
        static Caching()
        {
            _Synchronizer = new object();
        }
        public int GetMaximumCachedInvoiceNo()
        {
            
            ObjectCache cache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;

            if (cache.Contains(CacheKey))
                return (int)cache.Get(CacheKey);
            else
            {
                int MaxInvoiceNo = this.GetMaxInvoiceNo();

                // Store data in the cache    
                CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
                cache.Add(CacheKey, MaxInvoiceNo, cacheItemPolicy);

                return MaxInvoiceNo;
            }
        }
        public int GetMaxInvoiceNo()

        {
            lock (_Synchronizer)
            {
                int MaxTillLoad;
                GetMaxNumberClass MaxObtainer = new();
                MaxTillLoad = MaxObtainer.GetLargestInvoiceNo();
                return MaxTillLoad;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am concerned that if application shuts down my data will be gone. Should I save it in database too?

Comment: `please note I dont want to use something like Guid for this . I wanna guarantee my own logic.` why though? GUID exists to serve this exact purpose, you'll no doubt run into collisions and cause yourself more headache as time goes on.

Comment: i know this is not good in production. It isonly a practice for me. and I only wanna complete it to learn more and write some unit tests for a code which may have poblems. Guid is so good for this already

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you can store the maximum number in the DB. It's not a bad solution if you cache the number on application start up and handle updating it.

I am however concerned with your lock, you have a multi threading program and your lock is essentially stopping all threads and making them run synchronously.

I think a better solution would be to simply let the database handle all this logic by making the invoice Id unique.

If you want something a bit more complex than incrementing by a set value, you could also create a trigger at the database level.

Let me know if you need help with this :)

Comment: with this in mongodb `db.collection.createIndex( <key and index type specification>, { unique: true } )` hat happens after deleting some record ? will it still be unique? like when the maximum number is 26 and then we increment it with that custom logic to 27. and then someone comes and deletes 27 and now we need to make sure the second record is 28 not maximum+1 which is 7. so i dunno if mongodb handles it or i should go with caching solution ? and by caching i have to store it in a simple variable or i have to use a fancy way ? sorry i am too new in C#. sorry for my long comment too

Comment: Mongo DB will handle it, once a number has been deleted it won't reuse that number

Comment: Did you come right?